# Passing spool file name to SQL script as a parameter from batch file - unexpected behaviour

Tags: csv, batch-file, sqlplus

When I pass in a name for a spool file, I get an incorrect file name. For example, I double-click command.bat and enter 'TEST' (without quotes) at the prompt and hit enter. Script runs and queries that database properly, but my output file is 'TESTcsv.LST' (again without quotes). If I change the file name to a proper 'TEST.csv', I can see that the output is correct.

command.bat:

```
@echo off
SET /P name="Enter name: "
sqlplus username/password @script.sql %name%
```

script.sql:

```
--A whole bunch of formatting code
...
spool T:\&1.csv
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE somecol='&1';
spool off
exit
```

Furthermore, if I change the sqlscript to read:

```
spool T:\'&1'.csv
```

My output file becomes 'TEST'.csv. When I leave out the single quotes, why does it delete the  '.' in the spool file name and append '.LST'?

Note that the parameter being passed to the script is also being used in the query without any issues.

I've also tried passing the arguments using sqlcmd utility, but no luck there, so I'd like to get this working without sqlcmd if possible. For now, I can rename the file, but it is a bit annoying to have to do that every time I need to run the script.

Comment: If I edit the spool command to be `spool T:\&1..csv`, I get the proper output file. If anyone can tell me why the second '.' is necessary it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `&` is a way of putting two commands on one line. `dir & set`. This is command prompt specific. Enclosing in double quotes or escaping with caret. `Copy con c:\file^&.txt` or `copy con "file&.txt"`.

Comment: @Noodles In this case, the `&` is part of the SQL script, not command prompt. It is simply the first argument being passed to the SQL Script. The issue is that in the SQL query statement, the parameter appears properly, but in the spool command, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Found the following that answered my question when searching for another issue. Variable names must be terminated with a '.' to properly concatenate the variable and surrounding string. http://www.orafaq.com/node/515

> Now, what if I want to prompt for the user's name, like Fred, and set the prompt to FredPrompt> ? Simply stuffing the variable in there won't do:
>
> `MyPrompt> set sqlp '&EnterNamePrompt> '
>   Enter value for enternameprompt: oops
>   oops>`
>
> And neither will concatenating, since SQL*Plus doesn't accept concatenation for the values passed to its SET commands:
>
> `oops> set sqlp '&EnterName' || 'Prompt> '
>   Enter value for entername: fred
>   SP2-0158: unknown SET option "||"
>   fred`
>
> The power user tip to remember here is that variable names can be terminated by a period. Simply tuck a period between your variable name and the succeeding text:
>
> `SQL> set sqlp '&EnterName.Prompt> '
>   Enter value for entername: Fred
>   FredPrompt>`